# Command Status 0x00000011 with submit_multi for SMPP integration

Tags: smpp

Hi am integrating with Sybase Mobile 365 Services and I have gotten submit_sm and deliver_sm to work fine.  I am trying to get submit_multi to work, but no matter what I try I get back a Command Status = 11.  Does anyone have any thoughts as to what that command status means? Why I would get that? I have tried different service types and everything else I can think of... with no success.

Thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command Status = 11 (ESME_RINVDSTADR) means `"Invalid destination address"`.

This mean that probably the the `dest_address` field in your submit_multi request is wrong.

The `dest_address` field for `submit_multi` should be a list of destination address structures as defined in [SMPP 3.4 Specification](http://docs.nimta.com/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) - chapter 4.5.1.1.
The number of destination addresses in the list is set in the `number_of_dests` field.

Additionally, you could also check that the `dest_addr_ton` (Type of Number) and `dest_addr_npi` (Numbering Plan Indicator) are correct for each destination address. For more details about this check out this [link](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/type_of_address.html).

Comment: Radu!  Thank you so much.  That is awesomely helpful.  It turns out our issue was that the aggregator had our account provisioned wrong and we are only allowed to do deliver_sm and submit_sm.  They haven't provisioned us for submit_multi yet so I will definitely use the info above when they do.